# Change Size on Keyboard Fonts

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a board with buttons for all the letters of the alphabet, when a user clicks on one it types into the `Rtextbox`. Users can also use the keyboard, which then fires the `btn_click event`. However, when they use the keyboard text comes up as a different font and size causing the textbox to flicker

How can I set the font to be the same as when they click a button?

Thank You!

```
Private Sub btnA_mouseclick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles        btnA.Click, btnB.Click, btnC.Click, btnD.Click, btnE.Click, btnF.Click, btnG.Click, btnH.Click,     btnI.Click, btnJ.Click, btnK.Click, btnL.Click, btnM.Click, btnN.Click, btnO.Click, btnP.Click, btnQ.Click, btnR.Click, btnS.Click, btnT.Click, btnU.Click, btnV.Click, btnW.Click, btnX.Click, btnY.Click, btnZ.Click

        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim btnText As String = btn.Text 

    Dim holdCursorPos As Integer = RTextBox.SelectionStart
            RTextBox.SelectedText = btnText
            RTextBox.SelectionStart = holdCursorPos + 1
end sub


      Private Sub FormEnglish_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
            Dim key = e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper()
            Dim KeyClick = "btn" & key
            For Each Button In Me.Controls
                If Button.name = KeyClick Then btnA_mouseclick(Button, Nothing)
            Next

        End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the code that write to the textbox from the button click and the keyboard press. You must be doing something different.

Comment: added the code for both textbox and keyboard